# C# Anonymous and returning filtered properties with JSON

Tags: c#

What is the best way to return only few properties to JSON Result from a collection IEnumerable?

Department object has 7properties I only need to 2 of them in client. Can I do this using C# anonymous types?

```
    public class Department
    {
        public string DeptId { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
        public string DeptLoc1 { get; set; }
        public string DeptLoc2 { get; set; }
        public string DeptMgr { get; set; }
        public string DeptEmp { get; set; }
        public string DeptEmp2 { get; set; }            
    }



    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult DepartmentSearch(string query)
    {

        IEnumerable<Department> depts = DeptSearchService.GetDepartments(query);

        //Department object has 15 properties, I ONLY need 2 (DeptID and DeptName) in the view via returns JSON result)


        return Json(depts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // I don’t want all the  properties of  a department object
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var deptnames = depts.Select(d => new { d.DeptID, d.DeptName });
```

Then just use `deptnames`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I json serialize anonymous types all the time. Is a sensible plan.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq projection

untested code

```
var deptsProjected = from d in depts
                    select new {
                       d.DeptId,
                       d.DeptName
                    };
 return Json(deptsProjected , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```